# Build standalone XUL program based on Firefox's `-app` switch

Tags: firefox, xul, xulrunner

I've been working on a XULRunner based program for quite long. Since XULRunner isn't actively supported anymore, I kept running my program via Firefox with its `-app` switch. Now I'd like to build a standalone program, with an installer to distribute, but I cannot find any relating information. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is really pretty much the original use case. I've only personally seen it done with NSIS, but also Inno is mentioned in the documentation.

Here are some helpful links...

[Deploying XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XULRunner/Deploying_XULRunner)
Gives a high level overview.

The short version is that you need to bring your own installer solution, but one example is detailed here: 
[Windows Into setup installer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XULRunner/Creating_a_Windows_Inno_Setup_installer_for_XULRunner_applications)

Or, using NSIS, this stub:
[Sample NSIS script for XULRunner](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=299989)